# How to automate Dolhin Anty (playwright, python)?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python, dolphin-browser

I'm trying to automate work with Dolphin, but automation ends at the moment the browser opens. All that turned out to be found out is that in order for automation to go as it should, you need to open a new tab and close the start one
What should I do so that automation takes place completely without me?

```
import asyncio
import requests
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
import DolphinController


async def run(playwright):
    session = requests.session()
    auth_token = DolphinController.authentication("username", "password")
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {auth_token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    session.headers = headers
    current_profile_id = DolphinController.create_profile_and_send_id(session)
    automation_json = DolphinController.start_automation(session, profile_id=current_profile_id)
    dolphin_port = automation_json["automation"]["port"]
    dolphin_ws_endpoint = automation_json["automation"]["wsEndpoint"]
    chromium = playwright.chromium
    browser = await chromium.connect_over_cdp(f"ws://127.0.0.1:{dolphin_port}{dolphin_ws_endpoint}")
    context = browser.contexts[0]
    await context.close()
    context = await browser.new_context()
    page = context.pages[0]
    await page.goto("http://google.com")
    # other actions...
    await browser.close()


async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
        await run(playwright)


asyncio.run(main())
```

DolphinController.py

```
import json
import random
import requests

platforms_array = ["macos", "windows", "linux"]
vendors_array = ["Google Inc. (Intel)", "Google Inc. (NVIDIA)", "Google Inc. (AMD)", "Google Inc.",
                 "Google Inc. (Microsoft)", "Google Inc. (Unknown)", "Intel Inc.",
                 "Google Inc. (NVIDIA Corporation)"]
renderers_array = {"Google Inc. (Intel)": [
    "ANGLE (Intel, Intel(R) HD Graphics Family Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0, D3D11)",
    "ANGLE (Intel, Intel(R) UHD Graphics Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0, D3D11)"
  ],
  "Google Inc. (NVIDIA)": [
    "ANGLE (NVIDIA, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0, D3D11-30.0.14.7247)",
    "ANGLE (NVIDIA, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0, D3D11-27.21.14.6172)"
  ],
  "Google Inc. (AMD)": [
    "ANGLE (AMD, AMD Radeon(TM) Vega 10 Graphics Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0, D3D11)",
    "ANGLE (AMD, AMD Radeon(TM) Graphics Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0, D3D11-30.0.13044.0)"
  ],
  "Google Inc.": [
    "ANGLE (Intel(R) UHD Graphics Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0)",
    "ANGLE (Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0)"
  ],
  "Google Inc. (Microsoft)": [
    "ANGLE (Microsoft, Microsoft Basic Render Driver Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0, D3D11-10.0.19041.546)",
    "ANGLE (Microsoft, Microsoft Basic Render Driver Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0, D3D11-6.3.9600.16505)"
  ],
  "Google Inc. (Unknown)": [
    "ANGLE (Unknown, Qualcomm(R) Adreno(TM) 630 GPU Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0, D3D11)",
    "ANGLE (Unknown, Qualcomm(R) Adreno(TM) 630 GPU Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0, D3D11-25.18.10500.0)"
  ],
  "Intel Inc.": [
    "Intel Iris OpenGL Engine"
  ],
  "Google Inc. (NVIDIA Corporation)": [
    "ANGLE (NVIDIA Corporation, GeForce RTX 3070/PCIe/SSE2, OpenGL 4.5.0 NVIDIA 461.40)"
  ]}
cpu = [2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16]
memory = [2, 4, 8]


def authentication(username: str, password: str):
    options = {
        "url": "https://anty-api.com/auth/login",
        "data": {
            "username": username,
            "password": password
        }
    }
    response = requests.post(options["url"], data=options["data"])
    response_json = response.json()
    # print(str(response_json))
    if "token" in response_json:
        return response_json["token"]
    else:
        raise Exception("Authentication error, check your Internet connection and config data")


def get_new_user_agent(platform: str, session: requests.Session):
    version_number = random.randint(101, 107)
    options = {
        "url": f"https://anty-api.com/fingerprints/useragent?browser_type=anty&browser_version=107&" +
               f"platform={platform}"
    }
    response = session.get(options["url"]).json()
    # print(response)
    if "data" in response:
        return response["data"]
    else:
        raise Exception("Can't get new user agent, something went wrong")


def create_profile_and_send_id(session: requests.Session):
    null = None
    # set current parameters for browser profile
    current_vendor = random.choice(vendors_array)
    current_renderer = random.choice(renderers_array[current_vendor])
    current_platform = random.choice(platforms_array)
    current_user_agent = get_new_user_agent(platform=current_platform, session=session)
    # set options for browser profile
    options = {
        "url": "https://anty-api.com/browser_profiles",
        "data": {
            "platform": current_platform,
            "browserType": "anty",
            "useragent": {
                "mode": "manual",
                "value": current_user_agent
            },
            "webrtc": {
                "mode": "altered",
                "ipAddress": null
            },
            "canvas": {
                "mode": "real"
            },
            "webgl": {
                "mode": "real"
            },
            "webglInfo": {
                "mode": "manual",
                "vendor": current_vendor,
                "renderer": current_renderer
            },
            "geolocation": {
                "mode": "real",
                "latitude": null,
                "longitude": null
            },
            "cpu": {
                "mode": "manual",
                "value": random.choice(cpu)
            },
            "memory": {
                "mode": "manual",
                "value": random.choice(memory)
            },
            "timezone": {
                "mode": "auto",
                "value": null
            },
            "locale": {
                "mode": "auto",
                "value": null
            },
            "name": "Current Bot",
            "tags": [
                ""
            ],
            "mainWebsite": "",
            "notes": {
                "content": null,
                "color": "blue",
                "style": "text",
                "icon": null
            },
            "proxy": null,
            "statusId": 0,
            "doNotTrack": False
        }
    }
    response = session.post(options["url"], data=json.dumps(options["data"]))
    # print(response.json())
    profile_id = get_last_browser_profile(session=session)
    session.close()
    return profile_id['id']


def get_last_browser_profile(session: requests.Session):
    options = {
        "url": "https://anty-api.com/browser_profiles"
    }
    response = session.get(options["url"]).json()
    if "data" in response:
        return response["data"][0]
    else:
        raise Exception("Can't get list of browser profiles")


def delete_browser_profile(session: requests.Session, profile_id: str):
    options = {
        'url': "https://anty-api.com/browser_profiles/"
    }
    response = session.delete(options["url"] + str(profile_id))
    # print(response.json())


def start_automation(session, profile_id: str):
    options = {
        "url": f"http://localhost:3001/v1.0/browser_profiles/{profile_id}/start?automation=1"
    }
    response = session.get(options['url']).json()
    return response
```

You don't have to look at the DolphinController code, here it just serves to connect, in the original it is different, but the problem lies precisely in the connection